# Can links inside iframe that link to another domain be ignored/disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I need to make a reactjs app that has some whole webpages inside it. I'm using iframes for this. When some link that goes to a different domain is clicked the connection is denied. I understand this is intended behavior but is there any way to somehow disable links that would be denied so that when they are clicked nothing happens instead of showing an error?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, "the connection is denied"? Can you please translate what that screenshot error message shows into English for us?

Comment: have you tried to preload it in another hidden iframe, and check if loading is successful and disabled the link accordingly, or possibly make ajax call and check response header if it's x-frame-options problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable links in iframe like that.

```
iframe
{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```